# What is the difference between the two rules without prerequisite?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make, prerequisites

I have some difficulty to understand how to write a rule to let **Makefile** make a soft link on a file. It turns out that only write in one line works. Can someone help me understand why Make work in such way specifically for no prerequisite rule?

**make runsimq**  # it can create a symbolic link on *$(MY_LOG)* named *$(IT_LOG)*

**make runsimq1** # make: Nothing to be done for `runsimq1'.

```
MY_LOG = ./my.log
IT_LOG = it.log
IT_LOG1 = it_1.log

.PHONY: $(IT_LOG) $(IT_LOG1)

runsimq: $(IT_LOG)

runsimq1: $(IT_LOG1)

runsimq2: runsimq1
    @echo why say Nothing to be done?

# put target, prerequisite(empty) and recipe in one line, work
$(IT_LOG):;@echo create a symbolic link; ln -nsf $(MY_LOG) ./$(IT_LOG);

# put recipe in different lines, not work
$(IT_LOG1):
    @echo create a symbolic link; \
    ln -nsf $(MY_LOG) ./$(IT_LOG1);
```

Comment: Just notice there is a typo on varaible - IT_LOG1(mistakely named IT_LOG_1). Now it works.